# IllegalLocationConstraintException occur while attempting to upload

Tags: aws-sdk

When I trying to upload a pdf generated in local pc to the aws Hong Kong s3 server, I get the following error :

```
The ap-east-1 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

May I know how can I define the region to ap-east-1?

Comment: oh, I find the answer, just add it when declaring the AWS.S3 object.